# Break Line unless it is Empty

Tags: line-breaking, thmtools

I'm trying to write a macro that finishes a group with a horizontal line. If the line is non-empty, it should add a line break and the horizontal line. If the line is empty, e.g. the group ended in an equation, it should just add the horizontal line.

I'm aware of some quick fixes that do not suit my needs, e.g., I could leave the vertical mode, break the line regardless of what came before and add the horizontal line. However, in case the group ends in an equation, the vertical space is too large.

**Context:** 
I want to define a definition environment that is visually separated from the surrounding text by horizontal lines. 
For this, I use the following theorem style definition with `amsthm` and `thmtools`:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newcommand*\Vhrulefill[1]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1ex depth \dimexpr#1-1ex\hfill\kern0pt\noindent}
\newcommand*{\defheaderline}{{\color{lightgray}\Vhrulefill{1pt}}\newline}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries,
  numbered=unless unique,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  spaceabove=\topsep,
  postheadspace=1em,
  headpunct={},
  postheadhook=\defheaderline, % hline starting after the def label until end of line
  prefoothook=\noindent\defheaderline, % <- problem is here: needs to break line unless it is empty
  spacebelow=0.5\topsep,  
]{sepdef}
```

Another option would be to put the line in the `postfoothook`. This, however, often results in the definition being finished, then there is a page break, followed by the horizontal line on the next page --- Not exactly what I had in mind.

Thanks for any help!

Here is a (admittedly non-minimal) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand*\Vhrulefill[1]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1ex depth \dimexpr#1-1ex\hfill\kern0pt\noindent}
\newcommand*{\defheaderline}{{\color{lightgray}\Vhrulefill{1pt}}\newline}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  postheadhook=\defheaderline, % hline starting after the def label until end of line
  prefoothook=\noindent\defheaderline, % <- problem is here: needs to break line unless it is empty
]{sepdef}
\declaretheorem[
  style=sepdef,
]{definition}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
\blindtext[1] 
This definition ends in text.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
This definition ends in a formula.
\[ \epsilon < 0 \]
\end{definition}

Lastly, the following definition is not visually separated, so I want the concluding line to be in its own line.

\begin{definition}
\blindtext[1]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I did, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: you might find it easier to control the spacing if you used an \hrule from vertical mode rather than the `\leaders` paragraph in hmode

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that. Removing `\leavevmode\leaders` places the line over "Definition" and I fail to push it downwards. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround by moving the concluding `hline` in the postfoothook, so `thmtools` manages the line break for me. The problem of page breaks can be mitigated by setting the `spacebelow` to `0pt` and move the vertical space to the postfoothook as well.
Thus, the theorem style looks as follows:

```
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries,
  numbered=unless unique,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  spaceabove=\topsep,
  postheadspace=1em,
  headpunct={},
  postheadhook=\defheaderline,
  postfoothook=\noindent\defheaderline\vspace{.5\topsep},
  spacebelow=0pt,  
]{sepdef}
```